Timeout Issue with aiohttp but not with Requests
I'm trying to fetch a webpage in Python using two different methods: requests and aiohttp. The requests method works fine, but the aiohttp method results in a timeout. Here's the code:
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "Cookie": ""
}

url = "an_url"

async def request_requests():
    print("Requesting...")
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=3)
        print(response.text)
    except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
        print("Timeout REQUESTS")


async def request_aiohttp():
    print("Requesting...")
    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers, timeout=aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=3)) as session:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                print(await response.text())
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print("Timeout AIOHTTP")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(request_requests())
    asyncio.run(request_aiohttp())

When I run the script, requests retrieves the data successfully, but aiohttp consistently times out. Both methods are set with a 3-second timeout.
Interestingly, this issue occurs with a specific URL I'm working with. For most other URLs, both requests and aiohttp work as expected.
Any ideas on why aiohttp is timing out while requests isn't? What am I missing here?

If the other answers don't help, then check for query strings in the URL. Aiohttp will encode this, so you may be making requests to different URLs: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#passing-parameters-in-urls

So I compared the two HTTP requests as suggested, I noticed that AIOHTTP request didn't contain the "Connection": "keep-alive" header. After I added it, eveything worked !

Hmm, sounds like you have a broken server. On HTTP/1.1 all connections are keep-alive by default, the header does nothing. If on HTTP/1.0, the connection should close by default and not cause anything to hang. (I'm guessing the server is behaving as HTTP/1.0 while reporting it as HTTP/1.1, so the client keeps the connection alive, but the server won't respond anymore).

As the docs for Requests define timeouts:

timeout is not a time limit on the entire response download; rather, an exception is raised if the server has not issued a response for timeout seconds (more precisely, if no bytes have been received on the underlying socket for timeout seconds).

On the other hand, aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=3) quite explicitly is a time limit on the totality of the request.

There could be a lot of reasons why aiohttp times out but requests does not. Most prominently would be the way each of them handles DNS resolution and the way they use the event loop. In my experience, requests is more reliable.
